# problem on line integral using stoke's theorem

Tags: vector-analysis

[image]
In these line if we use Stoke's theorem in plane won't it be zero  on converting it to double integral as the partial derivative of coefficient of y w.r.t x minus that of x w.r.t y is 0 . but its answer is given to be 1 . if my approach is wrong why can't we use stoke's theorem here?  What alternate approach can be used?

Comment: Stoke's theorem (or Green's theorem since we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$) is about a closed curve. Is $C$ closed?

Comment: No. I got it . thanks